# possible for a procedure to have an argument?

Tags: assembly

I was wondering in assembly is it possible to have a procedure that uses an argument?
I'm new to assembly and not sure if this is a possibility. 
It would be great if this is the case since it would really stream line my code.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Read up on [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Comment: Can you show us some code (with comments, each line please) which demonstrates what you've done, and where you are confused ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is if something like this is possible:

```
call my_function, arg1, arg2
```

If this is your question **you didn't completely understand** the concepts of assembler and the functionality of the CPU, yet:

In assembler code one assembler instruction typically equals one CPU instruction. CPUs do not have the concept of function arguments at all. Function arguments are a concept of higher-level programming languages.

A higher-level programming language must "translate" the concept of function arguments into register operations. On ARM CPUs for example it is common to pass the first four arguments of a function in registers R0-R3.

The following C code...

```
myFunction(6,7,8,9);
```

... would look like this in assembler:

```
ldr R0, =6     # Load 6 into register R0
ldr R1, =7     # Load 7 into register R1
ldr R2, =8     # Load 8 into register R2
ldr R3, =9     # Load 9 into register R3
bl myFunction  # Call myFunction()
```

On x86 CPUs it is a bit more complicated because there are multiple so-called calling conventions which means that the way arguments are passed to the function differ from function to function.